# Why is there no more ~/.Trash?

Tags: xdg

I remember the nice `mv somefile ~/.Trash` command but that folder does not exist on newer Ubuntus. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the [freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/) [Trash Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec/):

> For every user a “home trash” directory MUST be available. Its name and location are $XDG_DATA_HOME/Trash ; $XDG_DATA_HOME is the base directory for user-specific data, as defined in the [Desktop Base Directory Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/basedir-spec/).

If the [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is either not set or empty, `~/.local/share` is used. So by default, the trash folder is `~/.local/share/Trash`.

Regardless, the easiest and best way to trash a file from the command line is to use the [trash[image: Install trash-cli]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/trash-cli)
command.

Use it like you would use `rm`:

```
trash somefile.txt
```

This is better than just `mv`'ing a file into `~/.local/share/Trash` because it stores metadata such as where the file was originally so you can restore (un-delete) it if need be.

Comment: In the version of `trash-cli` I installed today (2012-06-24), the command is `trash-put` instead of `trash`.

Answer (score 10):

You can find it here.   *~/.local/share/Trash/*

Answer (score 6):

it is because of the latest XDG Base Directory Specification: http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: I want to mark this as the real answer to my question because I it is a "why" question but the spec does not mention anything abut Trash folders. Could you please explain how XDG spec affected the .Trash convention?

Comment: @Aleksandr I have updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: @Aleksandr Updated DoR answer explains everything :)